# Magento observer on order status update/new shipment

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, observers

I'm trying to add an observer to my Magento extension. The observer should track the status updates and push them to an external system.

I have this in my etc/config.xml

```
<config>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_commit_after>
                <observers>
                    <plus_orderupdate>
                        <class>EffectConnect_Plus_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>orderUpdate</method>
                    </plus_orderupdate>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_commit_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

And this in my Model/Observer.php

```
public function orderUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $order=$observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

    die('Observer called');
}
```

Yet the observer is not called on a status update or anything else. I can't seem to figure out why, I tried all kinds of observers, like `sales_order_save_after`.
What could be wrong? Am I using the right observer?
All other observers in my extension work fine. This is my first time working in Magento, so I might be missing some basic stuff :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to disable and clean config cache when changing xml